# Cumulative points over year on map with R ggplot2 and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to plot new locations opened over each month on a map cumulatively. I am able to create an animation with new locations each month, but not cumulatively. In other words, I want to see the new locations add to the existing ones.

Here is the sample data

```
DF <- data.frame("latitude" = c(42.29813,41.83280,41.83280,30.24354),
                 "longitude" =c(-71.23154,-72.72642,-72.72642,-81.62098),
                 "month" = c(1,2,3,4))
```

This is what I have tried

```
usa <- ggplot() +
  borders("usa", colour = "gray85", fill = "gray80") +
  theme_map() 

map <- usa +
   geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, cumulative=TRUE,
                 frame=month,stat = 'identity' ),data = DF )
map

# Generate the Visual and a HTML output
ggp <- ggplotly(map)%>%
  animation_opts(transition = 0)
ggp
```

The output does not show locations cumulatively. I want to see all four locations in the end basically.

Comment: Would you consider using gganimate? Or only interested in plotly solution?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes I would use gganimate if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `gganimate` you can include `transition_states` to animate your points. For cumulative addition of points, use `shadow_mark` to include data behind the current frame.

```
library(ggthemes)
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame("latitude" = c(42.29813,41.83280,41.83280,30.24354),
                 "longitude" =c(-71.23154,-72.72642,-72.72642,-81.62098),
                 "month" = c(1,2,3,4))

usa <- ggplot() +
  borders("usa", colour = "gray85", fill = "gray80") +
  theme_map() 

map <- usa +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "black", data = DF) +
  transition_states(month, transition_length = 0, state_length = 1) + 
  shadow_mark()

map
```

**Edit**: To save the animation as a .gif, use `anim_save`.

```
anim_save("mapanim.gif", map)
```

In addition, if you want to change the width/height of the final animation, you can specify, for example:

```
animate(map, height = 400, width = 600)
```

[image: animation of cumulative points on map]

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I save the output either as a gif or as an HTML file?

Comment: You can use `anim_save()` to save as a gif - see edited answer for example.