# Is there a way to remove trailing as points are added to a map?

Tags: r, tween

I am using R to try and produce a map animation that gradually adds points to the map as time changes, much like the map [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adm3RB4ieXU).  So far, I can only get the points to add with trails in between each one.  That type of plotting would work if I wasn't plotting locations on a map that have no connection.

How can I plot my locations as points on the map that simply appear when it's their "year" (or other specified time)?  For example, adding several points in 2004, then in 2005, etc, etc.  I've tried all the transition_*() functions, and those don't seem to work, but maybe I've missed something.

The code I'm using to plot the points on the map is below:

```
Final_View <- Minneapolis + theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                                  axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = "darkred"), data = Properties, size = 1) +
  transition_reveal(Year) +
  shadow_mark(past = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "CLCLT Properties Added")
```

I created the variable Final_View and added my map of Minneapolis (the city I'm mapping) along with all the parts of the map I wanted removed (like the legend and axis ticks).  I then add all the points using geom_point with the data coming from a .csv that I read earlier on (that part of the code not shown).

Next is what I suspect is causing the issue, but I can't find a fix: I've been trying out the different transition_*() functions, but none of them add the points as groups by year and keep previous points added on the map.

Is there an alternative to transition_*() which will achieve what I'm looking for?  Or is there a transition function which I probably didn't try yet or attempted incorrectly?

EDIT: Wanted to add that I've looked into the enter.*() functions as well, but those don't seem like they'd be what I'm looking for, since, if I'm reading it right, points plotted with those functions disappear as new points are plotted.

Comment: Can you use `transition_states` as in this example? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734569/3460670

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Frustrating that I couldn't figure that out on my own with all the different transition functions I tried.